# Accessing grid value in client side Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MsgStatus">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="img" runat="server" 
               ImageUrl='<%# (Eval("Status") == "Sent") ? "Styles/Images/Green.png" : "Styles/Images/Red.png" %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Status" 
                HeaderText="Status" 
                ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Status" />
```

I want to get the value of status for each row in client side, so that in my image field(MsgStatus) I want to display green if the message is sent if status is messagenotsent I want to display red. Now the MsgStaus is displaying only red. Where am i going wrong

Comment: Yes, there is a column called status which has sent or messagenotsent, I am hidding this column in gridview. if the value of that row is sent I want to display green. but now its only red

Comment: Yes i meant in the same case as mentioned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to compare strings so you would need `Eval("Status").ToString()`. Also take care its compared in the same case `Eval("Status").ToString() == "Sent"` or `Eval("Status").ToString() == "sent"` these are different.